# How to update class attributes with load function

Tags: python, class, object, pickle

I have a class in which the method `save` stores the created object to disk using the pickle package:

```
def save(
        self,
        filepath,
        ):
    #CHECK ATTRIBUTE VALUES
    pickle_out = open(filepath+'.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(self, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()
```

Similarly, I want to add a `load` method that loads a pickled file and updates the object with the loaded attributes.

In my load method, I used:

```
infile = open(filepath,'rb')
self = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()
```

However, this does not update the class attributes. How can I write a load method that does update the class variables?

Comment: What about a static method that returns a new instance of the class?

Comment: I believe this problem is related to variable-scope. When you issue `self = <new value>` inside of a method (which was called with `self`), you don't overwrite the `self` that refers to the instance, you're "shadowing" `self` with a new object called `self` in the scope of the method.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example of your code that you're having issues with, and it will be easier for us to help explain exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: Following on @HampusLarsson - `self` is slot 0 in the function's local namespace. You can change the object in slot 0 to something else, but all that does is remove a reference to the original `self` object, it doesn't replace it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to replace the object as opposed to creating a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not using a C extension or slots, class instance data is stored in a dictionary. You could unpickle the class and replace that dictionary.

```
import pickle

class Foo:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def save(self, filepath):
        with open(filepath,'wb') as outfile:
            pickle.dump(self, outfile)

    def load(self, filepath):
        with open(filepath,'rb') as infile:
            self.__dict__ = pickle.load(infile).__dict__

f1 = Foo(1)
f1.save("test.pkl")
del f1
f2 = Foo(2)
print(f2.val)
f2.load("test.pkl")
print(f2.val)
```

It would make sense to pickle only `self.__dict__` because that is the unique data of interest.

I don't see any benefit to this over the normal way of using pickle - have regular function or staticmethod load and return the pickled object. That is the intended use of pickle.